# Using Angular route in webapi application

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I'm not sure how can I implement proper Angular routing in web api application. I'm able to open the pages using this approach: http://localhost:52876/HTML/app/borrower.html

The Angular controller loads fine and all functionality is there from the angular side.

Now, I want to be able to open the views in a bit better view, using ng-route, so for example http://localhost:52876/HTML/app/borrower.html will become http://localhost:52876/borrower.

I included the ng-route.js file in the html files which I'm using in my angular app.

Also in app.js I have this:

```
'use strict';

var modules = [
    'app.controllers',
    'LoanAdminApplicationController',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.router',
    'LocalStorageModule',
    'angular-loading-bar'
];

var app = angular.module('app', modules);


app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.when("/home", {
        controller: "homeController",
        templateUrl: "/app/views/home.html"
    });

    $routeProvider.when("/login", {
        controller: "loginController",
        templateUrl: "/HTML/login.html"
    });

    $routeProvider.when("/signup", {
        controller: "signupController",
        templateUrl: "/app/views/signup.html"
    });

    $routeProvider.when("/register", {
        controller: "signupController",
        templateUrl: "/app/views/register.html"
    });

    $routeProvider.when("/refresh", {
        controller: "refreshController",
        templateUrl: "/app/views/refresh.html"
    });

    $routeProvider.when("/tokens", {
        controller: "tokensManagerController",
        templateUrl: "/app/views/tokens.html"
    });

    $routeProvider.when("/borrower", {
        controller: "borrowerController",
        templateUrl: "/HTML/app/borrower.html"
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/home" });

});
```

The html markup (I removed the content):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
</head>
<body ng-controller="BorrowerQuickQuoteApplication">


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->

    <script src="/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Angular/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="/Angular/LoanApplicationController.js"></script>
    <script src="/Angular/services.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/loading-bar.min.js"></script>

<script src="/Angular/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea what I need to do in order to make this working?

Should I modify the RouteConfig.cs file or I need to do anything else as well?

Comment: what is error in your applications in routing ?

Comment: no error is shown, I can share teamviewer if you want

Comment: I think you click on menu but it is not route properly

Comment: I'm not using ng-view at all in the html files, is that required? @Singh

Comment: Please include ng-view in your index html, its required

Comment: @Laziale what about refreshing the page on specific view, how is the requests handled in case of asp.net in that case. Let's say you hosted your website on xyz.com/anything is supposed to show a specific view but the main request falls to your server or both things are conjoined in case of asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't navigate with the file name as you are doing that's angular route job to do for example

```
  $routeProvider.when("/borrower", {
        controller: "borrowerController",
        templateUrl: "/HTML/app/borrower.html"
    });
```

when you go to `localhost:8080/yourapp/borrower`

and you need `ng-view` in your index.html

Like this

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

your pages will be shown here.

router will look that you are requesting for the borrower and it will take you to the `/HTML/app/borrower.html` 
You are using html five mode that means you need server side routing to so it can fall to index.html every time so your `url` can be without hash.

Comment: Do you have few minutes for teamviewer? Thanks for your answer

Comment: 710 045 275  / 5630